# How to get mesos master URL through APIs dynamically?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos

is there a way to get the mesos master end point using a POST/GET call dynamically? Are there any APIs to call zookeeper which in turn returns the mesos master URL?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to query for the master in zookeeper by querying your zookeeper DNS endpoint (e.g. zookeeper.example.com) with:

`zookeeper.example.com:2181/mesos`.

You may also query any of your masters in mesos, and the request will automatically get forwarded to the leading master.

Lastly, there's a project called [Mesos-DNS](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns) that has a DNS endpoint for any of your mesos masters (with `master.mesos`).

However, the most important point is that *you shouldn't be storing that information*. There's no reason to assume that the current leading master (or any master for that matter) won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Use zookeeper command-line.

https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/trunk/bin/zkCli.sh

```
./bin/zkCli.sh

help
# see how to connect to other zookeeper
# default is: localhost:2181

ls /
# [mesos, zookeeper]

ls /mesos
# [json.info_0000000001]

get /mesos/json.info_0000000001
# It will return the Mesos Master's hostname & IP
```

The result is like this:

```
{"address":{"hostname":"ced7f7fb79fc","ip":"172.17.0.3","port":5050},"hostname":"ced7f7fb79fc","id":"c8055c4c-3ae0-40e6-a710-5184bcb957a9","ip":50336172,"pid":"master@172.17.0.3:5050","port":5050,"version":"0.26.0"}
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only a single znode in `/mesos`. However, this can't be assumed, and there is no way to determine the leader from the resulting json in the znode content.
Eg.

`[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 20] ls /mesos ###
 [json.info_0000000111, json.info_0000000112, json.info_0000000112, log_replicas]`

Answer (score 0):

With [mesos-dns](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns) you can simplye use leader.mesos to get the current master.

```
dig leader.mesos

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.6-Ubuntu <<>> leader.mesos
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8386
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;leader.mesos.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
leader.mesos.           60      IN      A       10.100.12.40

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.100.14.206#53(10.100.14.206)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 14 15:31:55 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```